# MS Chart: How to place axis label in the extension of it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, charts, axis-labels

I have a simple chart where a line rise from negative to positive: it crosses the horizontal axis. For readability, I did set the AxisY crossing to zero.

```
ChartAmortisation.ChartAreas("Amortisation").AxisY.Crossing = 0
```

But doing so, the label of my x-axis stays below, under the chart, while the x-axis is above in the middle of the chart area.

How can I set the AxisX label under the axis, or next to it?

[image: Axis label should follow the axis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded using `Annotations`. I made this for the two axes in order to preserve visual coherence. Here is my code for the vertical axis.

```
Dim caLabelAxisY As New TextAnnotation
With caLabelAxisY
        .AnchorX = 0
        .AxisX = ChartAmortisation.ChartAreas(0).AxisX
        .AnchorY = ChartAmortisation.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum 
        .AxisY = ChartAmortisation.ChartAreas(0).AxisY

        .Name = "Label AxisY"
        .Text = "Investition / Überschuss"
        .Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Bold)

        .AnchorAlignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft
End With
```

Strangely enough, setting the `AnchorY` did not work with the name of the chart, but only with its index. This means:

```
'What works:
caLabelAxisY.AnchorY = ChartAmortisation.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum  
'What doesnot work:
caLabelAxisY.AnchorY = ChartAmortisation.ChartAreas("Amortisation").AxisY.Maximum
```

Also, this only worked when I set the `Annotations` programmatically. Setting these in the Designer of Visual Studio 2010 helped me to visualise what the result would be, but did not display anything at runtime.

And finally, here is how it looks like now.
[image: Problem solved]

The labels are located inside the Chart for more convenience place them (otherwise I should bother with the size of the numbers on the axis)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do what you want, unless you derive from MS Chart class, and override the way it draws the axis title.
Instead, you can leave the X axis at the bottom, then detect whether the 0 (zero) value is among the Y values, and if this is the case -- draw a custom horizontal line at y = 0.

Comment: Thanks, that would also been a good solution. I prefer the solution I just posted, even more complex and have the drawback to have the labels on the "inner side" of the axis.